# asp.net mvc Error on aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, tags

I'm getting a only asp.net runtime error "content controls are allowed directly in a content page that contains content controls."

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <% using (Html.BeginForm("", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
       {%>

    <input type="file" name="FileUpload" />
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="Upload" />

<% }
        System.Data.DataTable dt = (System.Data.DataTable) (ViewData["dt"]);
        if (dt != null && dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (System.Data.DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count ; i++)
                {%>

  <span><%= dr[i].ToString()%></span>
        <% }%>
           <br/>
            <%}
        }%>


</asp:Content>
```

Comment: You missed the point of MVC

Comment: is this Webforms or MVC, I see `<asp:Content` in your markup

Comment: its my index page in mvc

Comment: MVC pages can't contain controls. `<asp:Content />` is a control.

Comment: I understand now. Not recommended to use server side controls. Are there ways around this ? I'm very raw in mvc please help

Comment: @user2433500 see my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "content controls are allowed directly in a content page that contains
>   content controls."

You are getting this error because you have added server controls to your view:

`<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">`

This require ViewState (webforms) such notion do not exist in ASP.net MVC.

Just as an example, your view would look like this:

**View**

```
@model YourProject.YourModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <input type="file" name="FileUpload" />
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="Upload" />
}

@foreach (var item in YourModel.data)
{
    <span>@item</span>
}
```

In your Controller you will put the logic.

In your Model you will put properties there for your objects.

Never manipulate data in your View.

Comment: my controller returns my index page because I'm using wcf and consuming my methods in the service with ajax

Comment: I will post another question after I try to call my method to post my  csv file to html table. thank you for correcting me and teaching me.

Comment: Ok please just make sure you include all the details in your post, as mine was just an attempt to answer the question

Comment: before I post another question, what happens if I have a lot of code ? do I include all of it ? I'm having trouble implementing my methods to my wcf service and consuming it on the client side.

Comment: You should only show relevant code if it is still too long use a pastie but if anything more info is better than lacking